# Возвращение не той ссылки в PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Помогите пожалуйста , у меня в коде есть строка

```
 $url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

И проблема в том, что когда я отсылаю запрос, в php файл, у меня выдаётся ссылка именно php файла, а как сделать, что бы выдавалась ссылка именно сайта с которого я отсылаю запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите видеть только адрес сайта, на котором обрабатывается запрос, то так:

```
$url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"
```

Или же вы хотите видеть ссылку с которой перешли то так:

```
$url = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"
```

Хочу отметить, что `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` может быть пуст и его нужно проверить на `empty`